# Problem installing Grub Customizer in Lubuntu

Tags: grub2, apt, lubuntu

I'm using Lubuntu.
I tried to install Grub Customizer but I have problems.
I used the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

But, I can not find `Applications > System Tools > Grub Customizer`. I also ran `gksu grub-customizer` in a terminal but nothing happened. What to do?

Comment: What errors did you receive? Can you add the output of your install to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Simply type `grub-customizer` in a terminal. It will ask for your sudo password. It should run once you type that in.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem, couldn't find a solution online, and did the following to get it working.

First, one line at a time, paste these commands into terminal and run.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
```

The repository had to be added before I could do the next step:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then,

```
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

After these steps, Grub Customizer still didn't show up in System Tools menu, which probably means the app is not installed.

Now, I'm not sure what is necessary to do and what is not, but doing the following got Grub Customizer installed and running. (Again, one step at a time.)

```
sudo apt-get upgrade grub-customizer
sudo apt-get build-dep grub-customizer
```

Finally, I went into synaptic, typed "grub" and grub-customizer finally showed up. I had to install it from there. Why it didn't show up in synaptic once the repository was added in the first place, I don't know. But, now it shows up in the application menu, launches, and functions at least on the first tab.